# What's wrong with my routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following routes declared in the `webApiConfig`.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here are the route attributes on the controller:

```
[Route("users")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()


[Route("users/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("users/validate")]
public IHttpActionResult Validate(string email)
```

When I make a call to:
   ~/api/users -- it works
   ~/api/users/1 -- it works
   ~/api/users/validate -- fails... trys to go into the api/users/1 but fails because of the Post verb.

How do I set up the routes so that I can validate a user in the user controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to register **Custom Route**, as you already have **Attribute Route**.

Remove **DefaultApiWithAction** route from your code. Instead, you will need **RoutePrefix**.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new [] {"value1", "value2"});
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        return Ok(id);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("validate")]
    public IHttpActionResult Validate([FromBody]string email)
    {
        return Ok(email);
    }
}
```

### How to Test HttpPost

Install [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) in Chrome browser. *You can also use Fiddler or some other tools.*

1. Select POST and enter URL `http://localhost:XXXXX/api/users/validate`
2. Select `application/json` as content type
3. Enter content `"johndoe@example.com"`
4. After clicking Send, you should see the result

[image]

### API Break Point

[image]

Comment: I was using fiddler to do that, but it wouldn't hit my validate route until I gave it the route: user/{id}/validate... now it works fine...

Comment: You can do `[Route("{email}/valdiate")]` in above example. Normally, if all action methods have `api/users` prefix, it is better to have **RoutePrefix** attribute at controller level.

Answer (score 0):

Try the use attribute routing to decorate the validate method:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

E.g

[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]

public IEnumerable GetOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }

Comment: I edited the original post, I'm already using the route attributes.... still doesn't work...

Comment: Try using the Route Debugger to gain some more insight: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/

Comment: Also, simply switching the order they appear in code should work too

Answer (score 0):

Test the POST action with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) as you can't do it using your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have not enabled [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enable). You have omitted the `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` on the `HttpConfiguration`.

```cs
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Attribute routing.
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    // Convention-based routing.
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

You also need to make sure you setup the routes properly on the ApiController as well

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController {

    //GET api/users
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get() { ... }

    //GET api/users/5    
    [HttpGet]    
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) { ... }

    //POST api/users/validate?email=someone@email.com
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("validate")]
    public IHttpActionResult Validate(string email) { ... }

}
```